# Spin effect not working during ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code.. But the spin effect doesn't happen until the ajax call is finished (which is pretty much useless)

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      async:false,
      url: "../../xxxxx/AvailabilityServlet",
      data: {action: "xxx", sku: sku},
      beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
         $("#submiticon").removeClass("fa-search");
         $("#submiticon").addClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");

    }
})

.done(function( data ) {
      result = data
   })

  .fail(function( data ) {
      result=null
  })

  .always(function( data ) {
      $("#submiticon").addClass("fa-search");
      $("#submiticon").removeClass("fa-spinner");
      $("#submiticon").removeClass("fa-spin");
  })
```

But if I add an alert, it throws the alert and then the spin effect starts showing up.

```
$.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          async:false,
          url: "../../xxxxx/AvailabilityServlet",
          data: {action: "xxx", sku: sku},
          beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
             $("#submiticon").removeClass("fa-search");
             $("#submiticon").addClass("fa-spinner fa-spin");
             alert("stop") ;
        }
```

JSP:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <form role="form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <div class="input-group col-md-6" >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="skuInput" placeholder="Sku" autocomplete="off" >
       <span id="submit" class="input-group-addon"><span id="submiticon" class="fa fa-search"></span></span>
     </div>
  </form>
</div>

$("#submit").click(function(){
 searchSku()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `async:false` from your `$.ajax` call. You are making it synchronous instead of asynchronous (the A in AJAX) and hanging the browser while it waits for a response.

Comment: Thanks.. I just overlooked that attribute. But when I'm setting the changes to those elements "before" the call (beforeSend).. isn't it supposed to make those changes and then make the server call? Sorry if its a naive question.. my exposure with Ajax and Jquery is very limited. Thanks for helping..

Comment: @Vasco: It does make those changes before making the call to the server. But while it's busy waiting for the call from the server to return, it can't do anything else, including animation.

Comment: Thank you Matt.. that gave me lot more clarity. Appreciate your patience.